# Python Discord.py - discord.Message.author outputting a strange result

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm new to the Discord API and am trying to make my own bot. I'm trying to get it to record the nickname (not username) of the person who sent the message "-clan". Example:

```
Surge - Today at 15:01
-clan
```

This should output the result "Surge".

However, instead, it outputs this:

```
surge epic bot!!!BOT - Today at 15:01
<member 'author' of 'Message' objects>
```

I can't figure out why it's doing that, so some input would be greatly appreciated.

My current code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("-clan"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, discord.Message.author)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just do `discord.Message.author.name` ,name is an attribute of the `discord.Author` class.

Answer (score 0):

`await client.send_message(message.channel, discord.Message.author)` Will send the `__repr__` of the author object to the channel the message is in.

What you want instead is `await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Surge!')` Since the second argument is the message you want to send and the first is the destination.

Also it looks like you are placing your commands in a big on_message event switch case, if im not mistaken and you are; I do not reccomend this. Instead use the `commands` extension, the async branch of discord.py does not document this well and is mostly out of use, first i reccomend you use the [rewrite branch of discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/rewrite) and read the docs about the [commands extension here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To send a message author use just `message.author`.